# Azure Managed SQL - ODBC Drivers

Tags: mysql, sql, azure, odbc, ssms

I have an Azure Managed SQL instance that I would like to use to connect to a MySQL server via a linked server used ODBC.  I have tried and this keeps telling me I do not have the driver installed or the data source doesn't exist.

Is this because it expects this to be installed on the Azure machine hosting the server?  I have seen mentions of people setting up an Azure VM to connect to the machine and install drivers / setup ODBC.  Is this correct?

Can someone please either tell me how to connect to ODBC using DSN from my PC, or confirm if the error is due to the VM requirement

For reference, I have followed numerous guides and still have the same issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want the *remote* host to connect to a MySQL instance, then yes, the remote host needs the relevant drivers installed. The drivers being installed locally is irrelevant, as the remote host can't use those.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, I got onto the machine now, just have to figure out the scripts needed to install ODBC